# Submit form with table - how to pass the selected row number on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, form-submit, html.beginform

Here is the Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public List<string> Datas { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
@model InventoryWeb.Models.TestModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Data)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data)

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Data
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Datas.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.Hidden("Datas["+ i + "]", Model.Datas[i])
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Datas[i])
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="SubmitTest" formmethod="post"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

How to pass the selected row number (the number of row on which user pressed the "Submit" button) to controller? TempData/Viewbag/whatever it is possible to use to pass this info to Controller site when Submitting.

Comment: You can use `HiddenFor` ie `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Datas[i])`

Comment: Thanks NKosi, could you please detail your idea?
To me it looks like "@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Datas[i])" is equivalent for " @Html.Hidden("Datas["+ i + "]", Model.Datas[i])". But how I could pass "i" value to controller? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should not use input type = submit. Just use click button event, and transfer row number in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote it, it will send all the data back to server for any row.

You can insert a form in each row:

```
@model InventoryWeb.Models.TestModel

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Data)

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Data
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Datas.Count; i++)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Datas[i])
            </td>
            <td>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.Hidden("rowNumber", i)
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="SubmitTest" formmethod="post"/>
    }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

But I prefer using javascript in this situations.

**Edit**

With JavaScript:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitTest"))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Data)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data)
    <input type="hidden" id="rowNumber" name="rowNumber" />

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Data
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Datas.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.Hidden("Datas["+ i + "]", Model.Datas[i])
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Datas[i])
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitForm(@i, this);"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}

<script>
function SubmitForm(i, btn){
    $("#rowNumber").val(i);
    var form = $(btn).closest("form");
    form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Mahmoodvcs, thanks for the info. The trick is - it is necessary to:
1. Submit all the data back to server for all rows
2. Pass to server the info on each row the Submit btn was pressed
Is there are any way how to do this?
Also is there any way how to pass "@Html.Hidden("rowNumber", i)" - that "rowNumber" value to server? That could solve the case.
Thanks!

Comment: @BayE added another method.

Answer (score 0):

use `<button>` to replace the `<input type="submit" ..>`, and set the row number in the value of the `<button>`

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Datas.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Datas[i])
        </td>
        <td>
            <button name="rowNumber" value="@i">Submit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And if the target post Controller/Action is different the current one, instead of setting `formaction` and `formmethod` in every submit button, set it in the `Html.BeginForm()` like

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Evan, I need to use the submit input type to send the whole form (with all the rows) to server. I.e. I need all the data from this form plus the row number where user pressed Submit button. And the trick is how to pass this row # to server site. Any ideas?